hiera doesn't pick up new files in environment folder
I'm in the process of refactoring some long-overdue stuff from an overblown "common.yaml" into specific files in environment-specific folders, and I'm hitting a wall: I can't get hiera to pick up on the new files. Or at least on none of the keys in those files.
The most perplexing thing is that the basic structure and configuration was already in place. We moved some stuff out of the common.yaml in the past and configured hiera accordingly, and that worked. For picking up on the new files, no further configuration should be required, as far as I know.
Here's the hiera.yaml from the project root:
version: 5
defaults:  # Used for any hierarchy level that omits these keys.
  datadir: data         # This path is relative to hiera.yaml's directory.
  data_hash: yaml_data  # Use the built-in YAML backend.

hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data"                   # Human-readable name.
    path: "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"  # File path, relative to datadir.
                                   # ^^^ IMPORTANT: include the file extension!

  - name: "environment-data yaml"
    glob: "%{environment}/**/*.yaml"

  - name: "Per-environment yaml"
    path: "%{environment}.yaml"

  - name: "common"
    path: common.yaml

As you can see in hierarchy, it is configured to pick up files from a data/${environment} folder and its subfolders. And we know this works, because it's picking up the files that were there before just fine.
Before, we had configuration for EC2 instances in there. The folder structure looked like this:

And a short example for the contents of one of the files:
ec2:
  containers:
    docker_version: "5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-bionic"
    docker_version_ubuntu20: "5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-focal"
    docker_version_ubuntu22: "5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-jammy"
    labels: "development"
    docker_hosts:
      grafana-development:
        container_instances:
          grafana_dev_container:
            - ensure: "present"
            - image_name: grafana/grafana:9.0.2-ubuntu
            - container_name: grafana_dev

And all of these keys worked, and continue to work, without issues.
So it should have been easy to make another subfolder with files in the same vein:

Example file content:

But hiera doesn't find the keys. When I run this, I get the same error as though the key was simply not there:
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'pi_cameras.software.controller.pi_camera_without_hat.gpio_blitz' on node 240422-26
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Can anybody tell me what I might be missing here? There's not really any more information if I run --debug, and I rebooted the puppet server just to make sure.
Additional information: Server can resolve key!
I could confirm that the lookup works when I run it on the server:
puppet lookup --merge deep --node 240422-26  pi_cameras.software.controller.pi_camera_without_hat.gpio_blitz --environment development
--- ''

The key is found and has the correct value (in this case an empty string, which is not ideal, but I've tried other keys as well and they are all fine).
Meanwhile, when running puppet agent on the node, I still get the same error:
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the name 'pi_cameras.software.controller.pi_camera_without_hat.gpio_blitz' on node 240422-26
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

The puppet module is using the same lookup strategy as I did in the lookup on the server above:
    class { 'pi_camera::controller':
      gpio_blitz                  => lookup("pi_cameras.software.controller.pi_camera_without_hat.gpio_blitz", { 'merge' => 'deep' }),

I've checked, the lookup doesn't exist anywhere else, just to make sure that I do not have a query with another merge strategy running somewhere.
The lookup path I ran on the server was directly copied from the error on the node, so there can't be some ridiculously stealthy typo in there either.
I've also disabled this particular key to check if maybe other keys from the same file could be loaded, but it's the same for all of them. Works on the server, throws on the node.

You would probably want to start here: https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/debugging_hiera.html.

Thanks, I was looking into that. Apparently the lookup works on the server, but not on the node. I've added the new information above.

My intuition tells me that the new data files have ownership / permissions / SELinux context  that prevent the puppetserver user (often "puppet") from reading them.  Perhaps they are root-owned for example, and readable only by root.  The puppet lookup command working would then be explained by you running it as a user that can open and read those files.

Doesn't seem to be the case. I figured out that I can read the root key just fine on the node ( lookup("pi_cameras", { "merge" => "deep" }) ), and that the hash I receive contains the right data. No idea why, but it's enough for a workaround...

I still don't know why the node can't look up the specific keys. However, what I figured out by now is that it can lookup and merge the root key (i.e. lookup("pi_cameras", { "merge" => "deep" })), and that I can retrieve the correct data from the produced hash.
Since this is the more efficient way to do it in the first place, I'm now refactoring the code to make the one lookup and then retrieve the required information from the hash. It's a bit more work than I was bargaining for right now, but it should be worth it.
However, while this solves my problem, it's not really an answer to the question... I still have no idea why those lookups didn't work.
